# Split string at any linebreak character but ignore if there is no text after

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string (value is from textarea control) like following:

```
1
2

3

4
5


6
```

I'd like to split with new line character to get the string on commas; however, in the case where there is no text after new linebreak (after `2`, `3`, and `5`), I need it ignore new linebreak as follows:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6
```

I have used `myVal.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/g)` but it gives result as `1,2,,3,,4,5,,6`.

Also if there is any new line at last it should ignore that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the below command,

```
myVal.split(/[\r\n]+/g)
```

`[\r\n]+` Matches one or more new line or carriage return characters.`split` function splits the input string based on this pattern.

Comment: This will also match multiple consecutive newlines.

Comment: @AmalMurali op didn't mention about this.

Comment: Thanks Avinash! it does work for me. One more thing, if there is any new line at last it should ignore that also? It should ignore the last new line e.g. '1,2,3,' should be '1,2,3'

Comment: @Nikhil yep, it should.

Comment: @Nikhil try this `myVal.split(/[\n\r]+(?!$)/g)` .

Comment: @avinash: It worked, one last thing, e.g. output: 1 ,2  ,3,4 how do we ignore the space found after any string while spliting? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Nikhil just add space to the character class `[\n\r ]+(?!$)`

Answer (score 1):

Just use `+` (one or more).

```
myVal.split(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)+/g)
```

The `?:` prevents capture which prevents the newlines from being inserted into the split strings.

Comment: Thanks for reply, how to ignore any new line at last if any?e.g. '1,2,3,' should be '1,2,3'

Comment: @Nikhil `.replace(/[\r\n]+$/, "").split(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)+/g)`

Comment: It works, one last thing, e.g. output: 1 ,2 ,3 how do we ignore the space after any string while spliting?